# multi-function tabs using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li><a href="#tab-one" class="current">Residential</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-two">Commercial</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-three">Agricultural</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tab-one" class="tab_container"> 
    <div class="quick-search"> 
    <h2>Tab 1 - Quick Search:</h2>
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <label for="quick-search-1" class="screen-reader-text">Quick Search:</label>
      <input type="text" name="quick-search-1" id="quick-search-1" value="" placeholder="e.g. search"/>
            <button class="quick-search-submit" class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="adv-search"> 
    <h2>Tab 1 - Advanced Search:</h2>
    <form action="#" method="post">
         <label for="adv-search-1" class="screen-reader-text">Search:</label>
         <input type="text" name="adv-search-1" id="adv-search-1" value="" placeholder="e.g. search"/>
            <button class="adv-search-submit" class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="tab-two" class="tab_container"> 
    <div class="quick-search"> 
    <h2>Tab 2 - Quick Search:</h2>
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <label for="quick-search-2" class="screen-reader-text">Quick Search:</label>
      <input type="text" name="quick-search-2" id="quick-search-2" value="" placeholder="e.g. search"/>
            <button class="quick-search-submit" class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="adv-search"> 
    <h2>Tab 2 - Advanced Search:</h2>
    <form action="#" method="post">
         <label for="adv-search-2" class="screen-reader-text">Search:</label>
         <input type="text" name="adv-search-2" id="adv-search-2" value="" placeholder="e.g. search"/>
            <button class="adv-search-submit" class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="tab-three" class="tab_container"> 
    <div class="quick-search"> 
    <h2>Tab 3 - Quick Search:</h2>
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <label for="quick-search-3" class="screen-reader-text">Quick Search:</label>
      <input type="text" name="quick-search-3" id="quick-search-3" value="" placeholder="e.g. search"/>
            <button class="quick-search-submit" class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="adv-search"> 
    <h2>Tab 3 - Advanced Search:</h2>
    <form action="#" method="post">
         <label for="adv-search-3" class="screen-reader-text">Search:</label>
         <input type="text" name="adv-search-3" id="adv-search-3" value="" placeholder="e.g. search"/>
            <button class="adv-search-submit" class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="advanced-search">
    <span>Advanced Search</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.tab_container:not(:first)').hide();

$('ul.tabs li a').click(function(){
  var t = $(this).attr('href');
  $('.tab_container').hide();
  $(t).fadeIn('slow');
  return false;
});
```

All this does currently is tabs the content relevant to the tab clicked.

I need this to firstly only show the 'quick search' every time each tab is clicked.
Then if the user clicks the advanced search span the quick search div is toggled with the advanced search div.

Would this be possible?

View my current [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WxDme/39/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just toggle the each one inside the current visible div

```
$('ul.tabs li a').click(function () {
  var t = $(this).attr('href');
  $('.tab_container').hide();
  $(t).fadeIn('slow');
  updateWord();
  return false;
});
// on advanced-search div click
$('.advanced-search').click(function () {
  // toggle both divs inside the visible div
  $('div.tab_container:visible').find('.quick-search,.adv-search').toggle();
  updateWord();
});
// function to update wording on div
function updateWord() {
  var c = $('div.tab_container:visible').find('div:visible').attr('class');
  $('.advanced-search').text(function (i, v) {
    return c.split('-')[0] == 'quick' ? v.replace('Quick', 'Advanced') : v.replace('Advanced', 'Quick')
  });
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/2MqsB/)

Comment: Thank you very much :) How did you get into jQuery and what would you suggest me doing to get better at it, learning resources etc?

Comment: Read through the items here and it should help you get on your way :) http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info

Comment: Also instead of just toggling the divs, maybe have a nice hide/show slide effect?

Comment: Thanks, maybe I could use you as a tutor ;)

Comment: is it possible to use the slideDown() for both animation? So every toggle of the div slides down over each other?

Comment: @Rob you can do something like this using slideUp,slideDown.. or else you will have to do custom animation to have them both slide down http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/Q2hNM/

Answer (score 0):

Just playing with your fiddle a little bit, I made these changes

```
$('.tab_container:not(:first)').hide();
$('.adv-search').hide();
$('ul.tabs li a').click(function(){
  var t = $(this).attr('href');
  $('.tab_container').hide();
  $(t).fadeIn('slow');
  return false;
});

$('.advanced-search').click(function(){
  var curTab = $('.tab_container:visible');
  curTab.find('.quick-search').hide()
  curTab.find('.adv-search').show();
});
```

Comment: Good but it doesn't toggle the advanced/quick divs and dosn't change the advanced search span to quick search like the above fiddle does. Nice effort though :)

Comment: Cool. I had a hard time understanding your request. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I find it hard going explaining what exactly is in my head! Cudos for trying to help though